# DSolve does not give a result

Tags: differential-equations

```
highP6 = D[y[t], {t, 3}] - Power[(Cos[t]), 3]*y[t] == 0;
ic1 = y[0] == a;
ic2 = y'[0] == -a;
ic3 = y''[0] == 0;
DSolve[{highP6, ic1, ic2, ic3}, y[t], t]
```

I cannot get the solution using the above code? Any help!

Comment: LOTS of DE do not have closed form solutions. If you could assign a constant value to 'a' then you could use NDSolve.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is variable coefficient ODE, you can try series solution. The analytical series solution will be accurate "near" the point of expansion, which has to be where the initial conditions are. More terms makes it more accurate.

```
ClearAll[y,t,a];
nTerms=10;
pt=0;
ic={y[0]->a,y'[0]->-a,y''[0]->0};
ode=y'''[t]- Cos[t]^3 y[t];
s0=Series[ode,{t,pt,nTerms}];
s0=s0/.ic;
roots=Solve@LogicalExpand[s0==0];
s1=Series[y[t],{t,pt,nTerms+2}];
sol=Normal[s1]/.ic/.roots[[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to Numerical

```
a=1;
nSol=NDSolve[{ode==0,y[0]==a,y'[0]==-a,y''[0]==0},y,{t,0,2}];
Plot[{sol/.a->1,Evaluate[y[t]/.nSol]},{t,0,2},
     PlotStyle->{Red,Blue},PlotLegends->{"Series","Numerical"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Reference:  [solving-a-second-order-non-linear-differential-equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72019/solving-a-second-order-non-linear-differential-equation)

Comment: I have proposed a SE site for maple, if you could help out to make it a success?
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107315/maple

Comment: @MMM I added my self there. But this was done before few years ago, and due to lack of interest, the proposal was removed. There is simply not as many Maple users as Mathematica around.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I will try my best. I am sharing it with people. You do too, please.

Comment: Ask a random easy question, please.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment**

Like *Mathematica*, Maple is also unable to solve the ode.

```
restart;
ode:=diff(y(t),t$3)-cos(t)^3*y(t)=0;
dsolve(ode);
```

[image]

> DESol is a data structure to represent the solution of a differential equation.